# Styling a link as a button

Tags: html, css, button, anchor

I made a `.btn` utility class to style `button` and `a` elements as buttons, but the `a`'s still look weird.

I'm trying to get all the buttons to have the same height, which is why I set the `--button-height` CSS variable. I also use it in the `.btn-square` class to make sure that the squared buttons (the ones containing an SVG) are equal in height and width. I also center the SVGs with `vertical-align: middle`. Yet, the latter style didn't apply to the `a` elements, plus there's extra spacing around the `a`
elements that I cannot explain.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap");
body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  background-color: hsl(40deg, 22%, 8%);
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: hsl(40deg, 40%, 94%);
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  --button-height: 2.25rem;
  height: var(--button-height);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn>svg {
  width: 1.275rem;
  height: 1.275rem;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: hsl(40deg, 22%, 8%);
  background-color: hsl(40deg, 40%, 94%);
}

.btn-primary>svg {
  fill: hsl(40deg, 22%, 8%);
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: hsl(38deg, 22%, 90%);
}

.btn-secondary {
  color: hsl(40deg, 40%, 94%);
  background-color: transparent;
}

.btn-secondary>svg {
  fill: hsl(40deg, 40%, 94%);
}

.btn-secondary:hover {
  color: hsl(38deg, 22%, 90%);
  border-color: hsl(38deg, 22%, 90%);
}

.btn-secondary:hover>svg {
  fill: hsl(38deg, 22%, 90%);
}

.btn-square {
  padding: 0;
  width: var(--button-height);
}

.btn-square>svg {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn-small {
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

.btn-medium {
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
}

.btn-large {
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-small mr-200">submit</button>
<a class="btn btn-secondary btn-small mr-200">submit</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-square mr-200">
  <svg width="96"
       height="96"
       viewBox="0 0 96 96"
       fill="none"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip0_14_188)">
      <path d="M44 80C44 82.2092 45.7908 84 48 84C50.2092 84 52 82.2092 52 80V52H80C82.2092 52 84 50.2092 84 48C84 45.7908 82.2092 44 80 44H52V16C52 13.7909 50.2092 12 48 12C45.7908 12 44 13.7909 44 16V44H16C13.7909 44 12 45.7908 12 48C12 50.2092 13.7909 52 16 52H44V80Z"/>
    </g>
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clip0_14_188">
        <rect width="96" height="96" fill="white" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</button>
<a class="btn btn-secondary btn-square mr-200">
  <svg width="96" height="96" viewBox="0 0 96 96" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip0_14_188)">
      <path d="M44 80C44 82.2092 45.7908 84 48 84C50.2092 84 52 82.2092 52 80V52H80C82.2092 52 84 50.2092 84 48C84 45.7908 82.2092 44 80 44H52V16C52 13.7909 50.2092 12 48 12C45.7908 12 44 13.7909 44 16V44H16C13.7909 44 12 45.7908 12 48C12 50.2092 13.7909 52 16 52H44V80Z"/>
    </g>
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clip0_14_188">
        <rect width="96" height="96" fill="white" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</a>
```

[here's the codepen](https://codepen.io/boriks/pen/ZEjWWaP?editors=1100).

Comment: `looks weird` is opinion-based and not a question. What should the button look like? What is the issue? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What is your actual question?

Comment: @tacoshy just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Add .btn class to this code

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: Perhaps, but I would like all the buttons to have the same height.

Comment: after adding this code vertical-align: middle; to .btn, it looks good.

Comment: a, button tags now in the same level vertically.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `display: inline-flex` instead of `inline-block`. Then you can center the text and SVG with `align-items: center` (cross-axis: vertical) and `justify-content: center` (main-axis: horizontal).

I removed the `vertical-align: middle` from the `.btn-square>svg` selector and moved it to the selectors `.btn-square` and `.btn-secondary`

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap");
body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  background-color: hsl(40deg, 22%, 8%);
}

.btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: hsl(40deg, 40%, 94%);
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  --button-height: 2.25rem;
  height: var(--button-height);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn>svg {
  width: 1.275rem;
  height: 1.275rem;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: hsl(40deg, 22%, 8%);
  background-color: hsl(40deg, 40%, 94%);
}

.btn-primary>svg {
  fill: hsl(40deg, 22%, 8%);
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: hsl(38deg, 22%, 90%);
}

.btn-secondary {
  color: hsl(40deg, 40%, 94%);
  background-color: transparent;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn-secondary>svg {
  fill: hsl(40deg, 40%, 94%);
}

.btn-secondary:hover {
  color: hsl(38deg, 22%, 90%);
  border-color: hsl(38deg, 22%, 90%);
}

.btn-secondary:hover>svg {
  fill: hsl(38deg, 22%, 90%);
}

.btn-square {
  padding: 0;
  width: var(--button-height);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;  
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn-small {
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

.btn-medium {
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
}

.btn-large {
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-small mr-200">submit</button>
<a class="btn btn-secondary btn-small mr-200">submit</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-square mr-200">
  <svg width="96"
       height="96"
       viewBox="0 0 96 96"
       fill="none"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip0_14_188)">
      <path d="M44 80C44 82.2092 45.7908 84 48 84C50.2092 84 52 82.2092 52 80V52H80C82.2092 52 84 50.2092 84 48C84 45.7908 82.2092 44 80 44H52V16C52 13.7909 50.2092 12 48 12C45.7908 12 44 13.7909 44 16V44H16C13.7909 44 12 45.7908 12 48C12 50.2092 13.7909 52 16 52H44V80Z"/>
    </g>
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clip0_14_188">
        <rect width="96" height="96" fill="white" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</button>
<a class="btn btn-secondary btn-square mr-200">
  <svg width="96" height="96" viewBox="0 0 96 96" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip0_14_188)">
      <path d="M44 80C44 82.2092 45.7908 84 48 84C50.2092 84 52 82.2092 52 80V52H80C82.2092 52 84 50.2092 84 48C84 45.7908 82.2092 44 80 44H52V16C52 13.7909 50.2092 12 48 12C45.7908 12 44 13.7909 44 16V44H16C13.7909 44 12 45.7908 12 48C12 50.2092 13.7909 52 16 52H44V80Z"/>
    </g>
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clip0_14_188">
        <rect width="96" height="96" fill="white" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</a>
```